# what frequency is the mosquito's whine?

Tags: entomology

I read on Wikipedia that mosquitoes make the sound they make by beating their wings-- when they are flying, and that the average frequency of the wing beats are about 600 hz.   I went and listened to a 600 hz tone and that is way too low.  Not even close to the sound a mosquito makes.  So I went and found this, which shows the average number of wing beats per second for 29 different species of mosquites:  https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Wingbeat-frequencies-for-29-mosquito-species-Bars-mean-wingbeat-frequency-are_fig1_351489590

and they showed frequencies that were on average EVEN LOWER than 600 hz.  Only one of the 29 species had a frequency higher than 600 hz and that one was only about 750 hz.

But when I listen to pitches of sounds, like from here:https://muted.io/note-frequencies/  the sounds that are even close to what a mosquito sounds like, are more like 2000 hz or 3000 hz.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look for a *spectrogram* of a mosquito buzz, and read about harmonics.

Comment: yeah look at waveform as well. try spectrograph too. https://www.google.com/search?q=mosquito+waveform&tbm=isch here's a frequency spectrum:  peak is indeed at 1000 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8521026/figure/fig1/AS:280254565371909@1443829303583/Waveforms-produced-by-a-female-An-gambiae-in-ssight-top-The-waveform-signal-was.png